# Creating an Oval from 4 points

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

I am trying to do a very basic shape connecting 4 points. I have a plot that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuQq3.png) currently. However I cannot seem to find a module that can appropriately generate an oval that connects all four points. The four points will all vary (they are results of a test, intended to show how much of each attribute someone has). I have found many modules to create rectangles, ellipses or circles, but none of these shapes will consistently align with the points. Is there a more generic module that can connect all four points in a shape more like an oval?

I've also seen some modules that could create an arc between two points, which I thought might be useful, I could do this for all four points. When I tried to do this, it required inputs related to the arc angle, which I would not know how to calculate. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Here is the code that I am using to generate the image shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Axes go from 0 to 100%
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,12))

x = [-40,-20,20,20]
y = [-40,20,20,-20]

plt.scatter(x,y)
ax.fill_between([-100, 0],-100,0,alpha=0.3, color='#1F98D0')  # blue
ax.fill_between([0, 100], -100, 0, alpha=0.3, color='#F9D307')  # yellow
ax.fill_between([-100, 0], 0, 100, alpha=0.3, color='#F38D25')  # orange
ax.fill_between([0, 100], 0, 100, alpha=0.3, color='#DA383D')  # red
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach creates an [interpolating spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splprep.html) through the 4 points to create a "basic form". An advantage is that it also works when there are 3 or more than 4 points.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 12))

x = [-40, -20, 20, 20]
y = [-40, 20, 20, -20]

ax.scatter(x, y, zorder=3)
ax.fill_between([-100, 0], -100, 0, alpha=0.3, color='#1F98D0')  #blue
ax.fill_between([0, 100], -100, 0, alpha=0.3, color='#F9D307')  #yellow
ax.fill_between([-100, 0], 0, 100, alpha=0.3, color='#F38D25')  #orange
ax.fill_between([0, 100], 0, 100, alpha=0.3, color='#DA383D')  #red

tck, u = interpolate.splprep([x + x[:1], y + y[:1]], s=0, per=True)
unew = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
basic_form = interpolate.splev(unew, tck)
ax.plot(basic_form[0], basic_form[1], color='lime', lw=2)
ax.fill(basic_form[0], basic_form[1], color='lime', alpha=0.3)

ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

The same approach also works when an oval form would be impossible to fit, or would be much too large:

[image: different point positions]

Note that [to uniquely define an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023800/finding-equation-of-an-ellipse-given-four-points/3023877), 5 points are needed (but not every 5 random points can fit an ellipse). If you really need an ellipse, to find the smallest one through 4 points is quite cumbersome.

Here is the start of an approach which defines an ellipse as the points where the sum of the distances to the two foci (`(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)`) is a constant `a`. Then some minimal `a` for which a solution exists could be searched for.

```
from sympy import symbols, sqrt, Eq, nsolve

a, x0, y0, x1, y1, xi, yi = symbols('a x0 y0 x1 y1 xi yi', real=True)
ellipse = Eq(sqrt((xi - x0) ** 2 + (yi - y0) ** 2) + sqrt((xi - x1) ** 2 + (yi - y1) ** 2), a)

x = [-40, -20, 20, 20]
y = [-40, 20, 20, -20]

ai = 85
sol = nsolve([ellipse.subs(xi, i).subs(yi, j).subs(a, ai) for i, j in zip(x, y)], (x0, y0, x1, y1), (-10, 0, 10, 0))
```